# List Data in table based on a condition of a column within the table

Tags: sql, pivot

I have table customers which contains phone number and phone number type. The phone number type includes H, W, M which are home, work and mobile. What I need is to list records showing phone number based on phone type. Example 
If customer1 has two phone records, I would like to get a list as following:

```
customer PhoneH phoneW PhoneM 
ABC      123    None   232
```

Below are the columns in `Cust_tbl`:

```
CustomerId, CustomerName, Phone, PhoneType
```

Comment: Try searching for [pivot and the sql tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+pivot)

Comment: And add the tag for your DBMS (Postgres, Oracle, ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/41007

```
declare @cust_tbl table
(
    CustomerId bigint not null 
    ,CustomerName nvarchar(16) not null
    ,Phone nvarchar(32) not null
    ,PhoneType nchar(1) check(PhoneType in ('H','M','W'))
)

insert @cust_tbl
select 1, 'ABC', '123','H'
union select 1, 'ABC', '232','M'
union select 2, 'XXX', '987','W'

select CustomerName Customer
, coalesce([H],'none') PhoneH
, coalesce([W],'none') PhoneW
, coalesce([M],'none') PhoneM
from @cust_tbl
pivot (
    max(Phone) for phonetype in ([H],[W],[M])
) pvt
order by Customer
```

Comment: Hi John - I know this is an old post, but I had a need to modify the query on the phone so I have a question. In your example above, you used only customer table, and did not join to any phone table. In my case, I have customer tbl, join to phone tbl through custID. In case to list all phones, how you mofidy above example. In past I used Conard  Frix answer to do multi joins to the phone table. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, Does Conrad's answer work for you?  If so accept that.  If not, please can you give a little more info on what your two (i.e. customer & phone) tables look like / what you're trying to achieve?  My guess is you can stick with the above code & just do a left outer join from customer to phone.

Answer (score 0):

There are different solutions to this depending on the database. For example Pivoting in Access is different then let's say Oracle. Also there are some missing requirements

1. What happens if a new phone type is introduced should the query add another column?
2. Should a customer has no phone numbers be suppressed or shown?
3. If a customer has more than one phone number of a given type what's supposed to happen?
4. What should happen if the customer name differs for identical customerId's (so much for 2NF)

That said this will produce the output given on what we know from the question on most databases.

It creates a "unique" list of customers with an inline view `c` . And then joins back 3 times to the the cust_tbl once for each type.

```
SELECT C.customername customer, 
       h.phone        AS PhoneH, 
       w.phone        AS phoneW, 
       m.phone        AS PhoneM 
FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT customerid, 
                        customername 
        FROM   cust_tbl) AS c 
       LEFT JOIN cust_tbl h 
              ON c.customerid = h.customerid 
                 AND h.phonetype = 'H' 
       LEFT JOIN cust_tbl w 
              ON c.customerid = w.customerid 
                 AND w.phonetype = 'W' 
       LEFT JOIN cust_tbl m 
              ON c.customerid = m.customerid 
                 AND m.phonetype = 'M'
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0ddaa/10)</kbd>

This won't address #1, is vague on #2 and is kinda of messy with regards to #3 and #4

To see what I mean by messy see what happens when you get [one bad row here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/57167/1)